# IPv6 communication Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ipv6

I am developing a Mac application to communicate with printers using socket. When communicate with one printer with IPv4 ip, i got response. But when i tried using IPv6 IP with the second printer i got error

> SocketStream write error [0x0]: 1 9
>
> Error reading stream! ,Error 9: The operation couldn’t be completed.
> Bad file descriptor

I use CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost function for the communication. Do i need to do anything when communicate with IPv6 ip.

```
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fe80::aee2:d3ff:feff:46c7"];
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)myUrl.path, 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);
inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];       
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

Comment: Using IPv6 link-local addresses requires you to use the Zone ID because the same network is used on all the interfaces, and you must distinguish which interface is meant.

Comment: When i add interface(en1) along with ipv6, NSXMLParser gets some response from the printer. But Socket is not working with that too.

Comment: The format of your IPv6 literal doesn't look correct. It should be something along the lines of `[fe80::aee2:d3ff:feff:46c7%en1]`. See [Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URL's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt), [IPv6 Scoped Address Architecture](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4007), and [Representing IPv6 Zone Identifiers in Address Literals and Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6874)

Comment: @RonMaupin I tried the format as you mentioned. NSXMLParser works fine with this format. CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost shows error.